# kotlin program error: no main manifest attribute in jar file

Tags: kotlin

I wrote a simple kotlin helloworld program
hello.kt

```kotlin
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println("Hello, World!")
}
```

Then I compiled it with kotlinc

```sh
$kotlinc hello.kt -include-runtime -d hello.jar
```

there was no errors and hello.jar was generated.
when I ran it

```sh
$java -jar hello.jar
```

it said there is no main manifest attribute in hello.jar

```sh
$no main manifest attribute, in hello.jar
```

I couldn't figure out this problem.
My kotlin version is 1.3.40, JDK version is 1.8.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to upgrade to version 1.3.41 and using JDK 1.11+.

Answer (score 16):

I came accross this answer while having the same issue with Kotlin and gradle. I wanted to package to get the jar to work but kept on pilling errors.

With a file like `com.example.helloworld.kt` containing your code:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println("Hello, World!")
}
```

So here is what the file `build.gradle.kts` would look like to get you started with gradle.

```
import org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.*
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
  application
  kotlin("jvm") version "1.3.50"
}

// Notice the "Kt" in the end, meaning the main is not in the class
application.mainClassName = "com.example.MainKt"

dependencies {
  compile(kotlin("stdlib-jdk8"))
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
  kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}

tasks.withType<Jar> {
    // Otherwise you'll get a "No main manifest attribute" error
    manifest {
        attributes["Main-Class"] = "com.example.MainKt"
    }
    
    // To avoid the duplicate handling strategy error
    duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE

    // To add all of the dependencies otherwise a "NoClassDefFoundError" error
    from(sourceSets.main.get().output)

    dependsOn(configurations.runtimeClasspath)
    from({
        configurations.runtimeClasspath.get().filter { it.name.endsWith("jar") }.map { zipTree(it) }
    })
}
```

So once you `gradle clean build` you can either do:

```
gradle run
> Hello, World!
```

Assuming your projector using the jar in `build/libs/hello.jar` assuming that in your `settings.gradle.kts` you have set `rootProject.name = "hello"`

Then you can run:

```bash
java -jar hello.jar
> Hello, World!
```