# Beginner Problems with Gradle

Tags: kotlin, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I am trying to make a kotlin project using Gradle (I am a beginner to Gradle), and want to build an executable jar file. I had the jar being built by `gradle build` but it was not executable because the manifest inside the jar did not point to my main class.

Everything I can find says to do something like this:

```
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes("Main-Class" to "com.something.mypackage.MainKt")
    }
}
```

**edit**: I now have the jar file being built correctly, but am getting this error when I try to run the resulting jar:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics
        at com.ajsnarr.main.MainKt.main(Main.kt)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 1 more
```

**build.gradle.kts**

```
plugins {
    application
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.3.70"
    java
}

// version = "0.1.0"
group = "com.ajsnarr"

application {
    mainClassName = "com.ajsnarr.main.MainKt"
}

dependencies {
    implementation(kotlin("stdlib"))
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs(
                    "src/main/kotlin/"
            )
        }
    }
}

tasks.jar {
    manifest {
        attributes("Main-Class" to "com.ajsnarr.main.MainKt")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Solved it.

For the first thing I asked (partially edited out), to modify the jar tasks, you use `tasks.jar { ... }` instead of just `jar`.

For the second problem (`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`), Kotlin programs with require the standard library to be included when they are run. To fix this error, you could specify the kotlin standard lib when you run the jar file, *or* you could create a "fat" jar file with all of the libraries included. There are several ways to do this.

For creating a big fat jar file, this answer helped me: [kotlin program error: no main manifest attribute in jar file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56921833/kotlin-program-error-no-main-manifest-attribute-in-jar-file/61373175#61373175)

Here is my working **build.gradle.kts** (edited based on sedovav's comment)

```
plugins {
    application
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.3.70"
    java
}

// version = "0.1.0"
group = "com.stuffhere"

application {
    mainClassName = "com.stuffhere.main.MainKt"
}

dependencies {
    implementation(kotlin("stdlib"))
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs(
                    "src/main/kotlin/"
            )
        }
    }
}

tasks.jar {
    manifest {
        attributes("Main-Class" to "com.stuffhere.main.MainKt")
    }

    // To add all of the dependencies
    from(sourceSets.main.get().output)

    dependsOn(configurations.runtimeClasspath)
    from ({ 
        configurations.runtimeClasspath.get().map { if (it.isDirectory) it else zipTree(it) }
    })
}
```

Comment: You nailed it :) The only thing that would simplify is
```
from {
    configurations.runtimeClasspath.get().map { if (it.isDirectory) it else zipTree(it) }
}
```
This allows for getting classes from all dependencies into the final fat jar

Comment: Finally, Man, I was tired of finding solutions on ChatGPT and on Stackoverflow. Thanks Man, as @sedovav said, "You Nailed It". Amazing Stuff. :)